# ArcGIS 10.4 Portal

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

Where can I download ArcGIS 10.4.1 Portal? 
I need Portal for publish my example task.
Only has in Esri, but I haven't permit to enter there.

Comment: You can't install just Portal. You need a Data Store and a federated Server as well. All Esri software is available through the Customer Care portal. If you don't have download rights, you'll have to coordinate with someone in your organization who does.

Comment: You can publish your data to a instance of ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in @Vince comment. I'd suggest the same.

- Try connecting to myesri (https://my.esri.com/)
- Then My Organisations tab
- Then Downloads

> "All Esri software is available through the Customer Care portal. If
>   you don't have download rights, you'll have to coordinate with someone
>   in your organization who does."

Be aware Portal requires some configuration and a server machine - not so easy. cf. @Vince comment : "You need a Data Store and a federated Server as well. "). I would add it's just the beginning afterwards !

It might be easier using Arcgis Online / AGOL, as suggested by @enolan. it's almost the same, but hosted by ESRI on the cloud.

- Log in to : https://www.arcgis.com/home/signin.html